# Automatically click the default button in the windows based dialog box using python

Tags: python

I am working on a project to handle windows based dialog box. When I click on a web link, it opens up a dialog box with the 'save file' and 'cancel' buttons. How can I click the save file button using python? It's an executable file(.exe).

I tried using webdriver.FirefoxProfile() set preferences but no luck so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 0)   
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting',False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'C:\Desktop\Python')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk','exe/application')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get('https://youtube-dl.org/')

browser.find_element_by_link_text('youtube-dl.exe').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on F12 and fin xpath:

Or simple use: [xpather](http://xpather.com/)

[image]

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "youtube-dl.exe"
    allowed_domains = ['youtube-dl.org']
    start_urls = ['https://youtube-dl.org/']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="pagn-next"]/a')  

            try:
                next.click()

                # get the data and write it to scrapy items
            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: i don't understand, explain me ...i know xpath but the point is to automatically download the save file(.exe). when i click a link using   browser.find_element_by_link_text('youtube-dl.exe').click()    it opens up  a dialog box after that i dont know know how to click the save file button